# Issues in OpenDDS Build

Tags: visual-studio, build, opendds

I am new to visual studio,(vs 2019)

I am trying to build example files in the OpenDDS directory

as in readme,

Instructions for Building the Example (assuming ACE, TAO, DDS, and MPC
are installed and configured): - **done**

1. Run Make Project Creator to generate build files:

Windows, VC 7.1:   perl %ACE_ROOT%\bin\mwc.pl -type vc71 StockQuoter.mwc
Unix, GNU Make:    $ACE_ROOT/bin/mwc.pl -type gnuace StockQuoter.mwc

2. Build the application

how to build this? I get
[importing window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSjCo.png)

after proceeding so many errors in vs,
cannot build,
why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to generate the solutions with the correct MPC project type, you are now generating solutions for Visual Studio 2003. Replace `-type vc71` with `-type vs2019` and build it again.